# Templated C++ Object Files

Tags: c++, templates, g++, ld

Lets say I have two .cpp files, file1.cpp and file2.cpp, which use `std::vector<int>`. Suppose that file1.cpp has a `int main(void)`. If I compiled both into file1.o and file2.o, and linked the two object files into an elf binary which I can execute. I am compiling on a 32-bit Ubuntu Linux machine.

My question regards how the compiler and linker put together the symbols for the std::vector:

- When the linker makes my final binary, is there code duplication? Does the linker have one set of "templated" code for the code in f1.o that uses `std::vector` and another set of `std::vector` code for the code that comprises f2.o?

I tried this for myself (I used `g++ -g`) and I looked at my final executable disassembly, and I found the labels generated for the vector constructor and other methods were apparently random, although the code from f1.o appeared to have called the same constructor as the code from f2.o. I could not be sure, however.

If the linker does prevent the code duplication, how does it do it? Must it "know" what templates are? Does it always prevent code duplication regarding multiple uses of the same templated code across multiple object files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It knows what the templates are through [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). The type of the object is encoded by the compiler in its name, and that allows the linker to filter out the duplicate implementations of the same template.

This is done during linking, and not compilation, because each .o file can be linked with anything thus cannot be stripped of something that may later be needed. Only the linker can decide which code is unused, which template is duplicate, etc. This is done by using "[Weak Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)" in the object's symbol list: Symbols that the linker can remove if they appear multiple times (as opposed to other symbols, like user-defined functions, that cannot be removed if duplicate and cause a linking error).

Comment: This doesn't address most of the OP's question.  It's true, but it's not particularly relevant for what's being asked here.

Comment: @templatetypedef - I beg to differ. *If the linker does prevent the code duplication, how does it do it? Must it "know" what templates are?* The linker knows through name mangling. Inline code - is duplicated, the linker has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @littleadv- You're absolutely correct, but your answer as is does not address why the linker uses name mangling, how the mangled names for template functions differ from regular functions, how the linker decides which versions to choose, etc.  I'm not trying to say that this is off-topic or incorrect, but rather that unless you already knew the answer to the question I don't think this answer will be helpful.

Comment: @templatetypedef I assumed clicking through the link and reading a bit would be enough, but added some more words for pedants.

Comment: Why doesn't the linker complain about a duplicate symbol or something similar? It looks like my .o files have some of the vector code defined in a `.text.mangled_name` section. Is the reason that they are in a different section?

Comment: @Chris - because it identifies it as a template and removes the duplicates. It's called "Weak Symbols". Added to the answer

Comment: @littleadv Ah, yes, I see the symbols with the weak attribute in the binary output. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is stated verbatim in the opening section of this documentation:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html

Answer (score 0):

Technically due to the "one definition rule" there is only one `std::vector<int>` and therefore the code should be linked together. What may happen is that some code is inlined which would speed up execution time but could produce more code.

If you had one file using `std::vector<int>` and another using `std::vector<unsigned int>` then you would have 2 classes and potentially lots of duplicate code.

Of course the writers of vector might use some common code for certain situations eg POD types that removes the duplication.

Comment: I am not worried about duplicating std::vector<int> and std::vector<unsigned int>. What exactly is the "one definition rule?" Isn't the definition of std::vector<int> created at compile time for both f1.o and f2.o?

Comment: the "One Definition Rule" is per object file, between separate object files you'll get two different instances of vector<int> if both use it. What's inlined - will be duplicated, what's not - handled by the linker.

Comment: In short, the one definition rule states that if identical template instances appear in more than one compilation unit, that still only counts to the compiler as just one definition for that template instance.  Basically, C++ has this extra step between compilation and object code linking for the specific purpose of removing these extra copies of template code.